# Laravel/AngularJS Корявый формат данных

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Доброго вечера. Обработчик в контроллере возвращает непонятный формат данных:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

В то время, если переходить на страницу в ручную: `site.ru/device/record/2131312`, приходит `[{"filename":"file1.jpg"},{"filename":"file2.jpg"},{"filename":"file3.jpg"}]`

Обработчик в контроллере:

```
 $app->get('/device/record/[{rid}]', function($request, $response, $rid) {    
    $record = \Models\Loading::select('filename')->where('rid', $rid)->get()->toArray();
        foreach($record as $file){
        $arr[] = array('filename' => $file["filename"]);
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

Сама функция, что делает запрос на контроллер:

```
$scope.record = function(rid) {
                console.log('Отправляем: '+rid);
                $http.get('http://site.ru/device/record/'+rid)
                    .then(function success(response) {
                        console.log('Ответ: '+response.data);
                        $scope.records = response.data;
                    }, function error(err) {
                        console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
                    });
            };
```

В чём здесь ошибка? Возможно необходимо распарсивать ответ или что-то ещё?

Comment: А Вы попробуйте заменить `+` на `,`: `console.log('Ответ: ', response.data);`

Comment: премного благодарен!